# Passing Data to RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I make a call to retrofit, and the size of the response is what I want to pass as the primary data set for my RecyclerView adapter. I can confirm I am successfully calling to Retrofit.

I am curious how I would pass the size of the data set to MyAdapter class. Below is my code:

In my Main Activity:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Recipe>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Recipe>> call, Response<List<Recipe>> response) {
            Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(response.isSuccessful()));
            mRecipeListResponse = response.body();
            for (Recipe recipe : mRecipeListResponse){
                Log.v("ID", recipe.getId().toString());
            }

            mAdapter.setDataSet(mRecipeListResponse);
            mRecipeList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  ;            }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Recipe>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("TAG", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Recipe> mRecipeDataSet;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    protected CardView mCardView;
    protected TextView mTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_cardview);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_of_recipe_item);
    }
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recipe_item, parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String id = mRecipeDataSet.get(position).getId();
        holder.mTextView.setText(id);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mRecipeDataSet.size();
}

public List<Recipe> setDataSet(List<Recipe> recipeList){
    return mRecipeDataSet;
}

public List<Recipe> getmRecipeDataSet() {
    return mRecipeDataSet;
}
}
```

Comment: I think to not have understood. You're already passing the whole data to that Adapter using "setDataSet()", so the Adapter can already get data size from that method...

Comment: I was originally receiving null pointer

Comment: Where? Please be more precise. The only thing to say about your code is about "onResponse()" method: if this method is called from the Background Thread than it could be wrong to call "Adapter.setAdapter()" from there because this command should be executed in the UiThread.

Comment: create constructor in adapter and pass mRecipeListResponse and assign in adapter mRecipeDataSet =mRecipeListResponse  in constructor. And change mAdapter.setDataSet(mRecipeListResponse); to mAdapter=new MyAdapter (mRecipeListResponse);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you initiate the `MyAdapter` with null `mRecipeDataSet`. Try the following code.

```
private List<Recipe> mRecipeDataSet = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
```

and replace your code

```
//this is wrong, it doesn't do the right thing as the function name suggests.
public List<Recipe> setDataSet(List<Recipe> recipeList){
    return mRecipeDataSet;
}
```

to

```
public void setDataSet(List<Recipe> recipeList){
    mRecipeDataSet = recipeList;
}
```

Comment: Do I change this in the MainActivity or Adapter class?

Comment: your adapter class

Comment: thanks tried, still not populating any data, full code available here: https://github.com/troy21688/KitchenPal

Comment: no population of data and there is no error as well?

Comment: correct, I am inclined to believe it is my viewholder but unsure